# WPF tab control item is selected, but ui doesn't change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabs

I have this custom tab control and it works perfectly so far except for one thing. That tab control allows users to un-dock tabs as windows and re-dock tabs. The tab un-docks fine, but when the user re-docks it, it adds the item, but doesn't show that it is selected.

Here is the code for re-docking....

```
//find window
        DependencyObject window = sender as UIElement;
        while (!(window is Window) && window != null)
        {
            window = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(window);
        }
        Window currentWindow = window as Window;

        //redock window
        if (CurrentTabControl != null)
        {
            TabItem tab = new TabItem();

            //add header text
            tab.Header = currentWindow.Title;

            //add frame to tab
            tab.Content = currentWindow.Content;

            //add tab to tab control
            CurrentTabControl.Items.Add(tab);

            //select tab
            CurrentTabControl.SelectedItem = tab;
        }

        //close window
        currentWindow.Close();
```

Now, to the tab control this item is in fact docked. It calls the selection changed event on the tab control. But the the ui doesn't change for some reason. The other item is still selected in that way. I don't know if I can do a refresh on that or what but it's being pretty weird.

Thanks!

/////EDIT///////

So the first piece of code is being called from a button on a custom window that I made. I don't know if that has anything to so with it. I also have a method that adds pages to the tab control and that works fine. Here it is...

```
public Tuple<TabItem, Page> AddNewPage(Type pageType, string header)
    {
        //create new tab
        TabItem tab = new TabItem();

        //add header text
        tab.Header = header;

        //create new frame
        Frame frame = new Frame();

        //create new Page
        Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);

        //navigate to page
        frame.Navigate(page);

        //add frame to tab
        tab.Content = frame;

        //add tab to tab control
        CurrentTabControl.Items.Add(tab);

        //select tab
        CurrentTabControl.SelectedItem = tab;

        return new Tuple<TabItem, Page>(tab, page);
    }
```

/////SOLUTION//////
Apparently I needed to select that tab after the window was closed. So I just reorganized the code a bit and it works!

```
//find window
        DependencyObject window = sender as UIElement;
        while (!(window is Window) && window != null)
        {
            window = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(window);
        }
        Window currentWindow = window as Window;

        TabItem tab = new TabItem();

        //add header text
        tab.Header = currentWindow.Title;

        //add frame to tab
        tab.Content = currentWindow.Content;

        //close window
        currentWindow.Close();

        //redock window
        if (CurrentTabControl != null)
        {
            //add tab to tab control
            CurrentTabControl.Items.Add(tab);

            //select tab
            CurrentTabControl.SelectedItem = tab;
        }
```

Comment: Do you need to call OnPropertyChanged() to update the UI? This is assuming you're doing MVVM, which might be wrong.

Comment: Don't think so, I add tabs elsewhere in the code and they get selected fine.

Comment: What are you doing with the returned `Tuple`?

Comment: put breakpoint on CurrentTabControl.SelectedItem = tab; and see the value is set or does it turn back to null . if it turns to null then you will have to set selecteditem in load event of the tabcontrol.once i had the same kind of problem this issue comes when the control is not loaded.Or set it using Binding

Comment: Would love to use XAML for that stuff HighCore, but I don't think that is possible with what I have to do with it.

Comment: For some reason, after the window close event, it re-fires the selection changed event and that's where it is going back.

Comment: Got it to work!

I just reorganized the code so that the tab is selected after the window is closed.